# Why someone use descriptors with /dev/null?

Tags: file-descriptors

I don't get it. I see in some tutorials that people use descriptors like that (for output and errors)

```
command 1> /dev/null
command 2> /dev/null
```

But why they do that? We can't see the output on our screen or in a file. It just disappears. Do they test command or something like that?

Comment: Well, sometimes you don't _want_ to see the output, or errors...

Comment: It is quite common to want to hide error messages, or all output, and just use the result status of a command. Also, a "quiet" command option (as in `grep -q `) is relatively recent: redirection would be the equivalent in older Unix versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you just don't want to see the output. A lot of tools print a lot of "useless" stuff on stdout or stderr and sometimes we just want to ignore it and if the tool doesn't support something like `-q/--quite` redirecting the output to `/dev/null` does the job. If the primary function of the tool is not to print something, you might be interested only if it succeeded or failed and for that you'll use the return code (especially in scripts).

Example might be trying to figure out whether a tool is installed or not. You might want to check something like `tool --version` or `which tool` but you are not really interested in the version or path of the tool, you only care whether it's available or not and for that return code is enough. For example in a script where you want to check that user has all the necessary dependencies

```
$ which xyz >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo "you need to install xyz to proceed"
you need to install xyz to proceed
```

looks better than

```
$ which xyz || echo "you need to install xyz to proceed"
/usr/bin/which: no xyz in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/vtrefny/.local/bin:/home/vtrefny/bin)
you need to install xyz to proceed
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation!